# Inserting JSON data to remote Postgres table with Python Psycopg2 taking too long time.Is this the right approach?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, analytics, psycopg2

I have 2GB json data from Mongodb export.I am trying make some analytics with those data and post those analytics data into remote Postgres table.This is my code:

```
import json

from psycopg2 import connect, Error
import dateutil.parser as parser
from datetime import datetime

record_list = []

for line in open('december.json', 'r'):
    record_list.append(json.loads(line))

    #print(record_list[0])
    


    devices = []

    for key, values in record_list[0].items():


       if key == "deviceSerial":
          devices.append(values)
    test_list = list(set(devices)) 
    device_data = []

    for x in test_list:
        device_1 = [i for i in record_list if (i['deviceSerial'] == x)] 
        datetime_object_first = parser.parse(device_1[0]['createdAt'],fuzzy=True) 
        datetime_object_last = parser.parse(device_1[len(device_1)-1]['createdAt'],fuzzy=True) 

        devices = device_1[0]['deviceSerial']
        device_model = device_1[0]['device']
        device_Usage=round((datetime.timestamp(datetime_object_last)-datetime.timestamp(datetime_object_first))/60/1000,3)


        #calculating device usage
        device_data_elements ={

            'deviceModel': device_model,
            'deviceSerial':devices,
            'deviceUsageInMin':device_Usage
     
        }

        device_data.append(device_data_elements)

        if type(device_data) == list:



            first_record = device_data[0]


        columns = list(first_record.keys())

        #print ("\ncolumn names:", columns)

        #print(device_data)

        table_name = "test_data"
sql_string = 'INSERT INTO {} '.format( table_name )
sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(columns) + ")\nVALUES "



# enumerate over the record
for i, record_dict in enumerate(device_data):

    # iterate over the values of each record dict object
    values = []
    for col_names, val in record_dict.items():

        if type(val) == str:
          
            val = val.replace("'", "''")
            val = "'" + val + "'"

        values += [ str(val) ]

        # join the list of values and enclose record in parenthesis
    sql_string += "(" + ', '.join(values) + "),\n"

# remove the last comma and end statement with a semicolon
sql_string = sql_string[:-2] + ";"

print ("\nSQL statement:")
print (sql_string)

try:
    # declare a new PostgreSQL connection object
    conn = connect(
        dbname = "events_data",
        user = "chao",
        host = "localhost",
        
        # attempt to connect for 10 seconds then raise exception
        connect_timeout = 10
    )

    cur = conn.cursor()
    print ("\ncreated cursor object:", cur)
    
#Post data into postgres table
except (Exception, Error) as err:
    print ("\npsycopg2 connect error:", err)
    conn = None
    cur = None

if cur != None:

    try:
        
        cur.execute( sql_string )
        conn.commit()

        print ('\nfinished INSERT INTO execution')

    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("\nexecute_sql() error:", error)
        conn.rollback()

    # close the cursor and connection
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

I am doing some calculations(analytics) with this script.So there is some for loop in the script.When data length is less, script inserts those analysis into Postgres successfully.If data length is big, it takes too long time and I waited even 12h but no success .Right now my script is running locally and reading data also locally.What would be the best approach to read and manipulate large volume data and post the analytics to Postgres table.This is my sample json data.

```
[
    {
   "createdAt": "Fri Nov 27 2020 08:07:39 GMT+0000 ",
   "sessionId": null,
   "text": null,
   "device": null,
   "deviceSerial": null
 },
 {
   "createdAt": "Tue Sep 01 2020 06:59:18 GMT+0000",
   "sessionId": null,
   "text": "Approve",
   "device": "Android",
   "deviceSerial": null
 },
 {
   "createdAt": "Wed Sep 02 2020 08:40:10 GMT+0000",
   "pageTitle": "submit option",
   "sessionId": null,
   "text": "launchComponent",
   "device": "Android",
   "deviceSerial": "636363636890"
 },
 {
   "createdAt": "Wed Sep 02 2020 08:40:11",
   "pageTitle": "quick check",
   "sessionId": "88958d89c65f4fcea56e148a5a2838cfhdhdhd",
   "text": "",
   "device": "Android",
   "deviceSerial": "6625839827"
 }
]
```

Comment: Don't build SQL as strings. It's not safe. Use [psycopg2's SQL composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). "*I am doing some calculations(analytics) with this script.*" Consider instead inserting the data into Postgres and doing the analysis in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend dumping the JSON into Postgres and doing the analysis in Postgres. That's what Postgres good at. No processing of the JSON is necessary, you can directly turn the JSON array into Postgres rows.

One option is to make a table with a single `jsonb` column and insert each item as a row using `jsonb_array_elements`.

```
create table devices_json (
    data jsonb
)

insert into devices_json (data)
select * from jsonb_array_elements('
[
 {
   "createdAt": "Fri Nov 27 2020 08:07:39 GMT+0000 ",
   "sessionId": null,
   "text": null,
   "device": null,
   "deviceSerial": null
 },
 ...and so on...
]
')
```

Then do your analysis in Postgres using [its JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

If the fields are well known, you can use `json_populate_recordset` to insert the fields into individual columns of a traditional SQL table. Then you have a traditional SQL table which may be easier to work with.

```
-- NOTE Postgres columns are case-sensitive, so they must be quoted to
-- ensure they exactly match the JSON keys
create table devices (
   "createdAt" timestamp,
   "sessionId" text,
   "text" text,
   device text,
   "deviceSerial" text,
   "pageTitle" text
);

insert into devices
select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::devices, '
[
 {
   "createdAt": "Fri Nov 27 2020 08:07:39 GMT+0000 ",
   "sessionId": null,
   "text": null,
   "device": null,
   "deviceSerial": null
 },
 ...and so on...
]
')
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=846d4e9fa2df706f1a137ac1acb63b61).

You can also do a hybrid of the two: dump the JSON array into a jsonb column and pull it apart into individual columns inside Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Bulk inserts in Posgres is best done by cursor.copy_from.

Transform your json to the needed structure in Python, then write to a io.TextIO memory file. Push that to the db in one call to copy_from(). Do a seek(0) on the TextIO object before copy_from.

```
import io
import psycopg2

buf = io.StringIO()
buf.write('1|{"x":0}\n')
buf.write('2|{"y":0}\n')
buf.seek(0)

with psycopg2.connect(service="my_service") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("create table if not exists t (a int, b jsonb)")
    cur.copy_from(buf, "t", sep="|")
    print(cur.rowcount)
```

Insert to postgres cannot be done faster than this.

cursor.copy_expert can do the same with a bit more flexibility.

Regards Niels

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Schwern.It's really good help.I want to make my analytics dynamically.For example I want to sort column of deviceSerial and calculate its's usage from the difference individually from last and first index.This is my analytics.There will be thousands of row of data.I want to post those analytics to another table.I was thinking to fetch those Postgres row in Python again and make some calculations and push the result to Postgres.Would it be a good approach?Or I can do it, not fetching data from Postgres.Instead with python command for Postgres.